# Flipping two sides of string

Tags: r, regex

I need to prepare a certain dataset for analysis. What I have is a table with column names (obviously). The column names are as follows (sample `colnames`):

```
"X99_NORM", "X101_NORM", "X76_110_T02_09747", "X30_NORM"
```

(this is a vector, for those not familiair with R  `colnames()` function)

Now, what I want is simply to flip the values in front of, and after the underscore. e.g. `X99_NORM` becomes `NORM_X99`. Note that I want this only for the column names which contain `NORM` in their name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some other base R options

**1)**

Use `sub` to switch the beginning and end - we can make use of capturing groups here.

```
x <- sub(pattern = "(^X\\d+)_(NORM$)", replacement = "\\2_\\1", x = x)
```

Result

```
x
# [1] "NORM_X99"          "NORM_X101"         "X76_110_T02_09747" "NORM_X30"
```

**2)**

A regex-free approach that might be more efficient using `chartr`, `dirname` and `paste`. But we need to get the indices of the columns that contain "NORM" first

```
idx <- grep(x = x, pattern = "NORM", fixed = TRUE)
x[idx] <- paste0("NORM_", dirname(chartr("_", "/", x[idx])))
x
```

**data**

```
x <- c("X99_NORM", "X101_NORM", "X76_110_T02_09747", "X30_NORM")
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. This seems like eveyrhting i want. ill test it asap

Answer (score 5):

```
x = c("X99_NORM", "X101_NORM", "X76_110_T02_09747", "X30_NORM")
replace(x,
        grepl("NORM", x),
        sapply(strsplit(x[grepl("NORM", x)], "_"), function(x){
            paste(rev(x), collapse = "_")
        }))
#[1] "NORM_X99"          "NORM_X101"         "X76_110_T02_09747" "NORM_X30"
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution with `stringr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

my_data <- tibble(column = c("X99_NORM", "X101_NORM", "X76_110_T02_09747", "X30_NORM"))

my_data %>%
filter(str_detect(column, "NORM")) %>%
mutate(column_2 = paste0("NORM", "_", str_extract(column, ".+(?=_)"))) %>%
select(column_2)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  column_2 
  <chr>    
1 NORM_X99 
2 NORM_X101
3 NORM_X30
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i will test it asap